# SQL count distinct id too slow (~7 seconds)

Tags: postgresql

I have a query as such:

```
SELECT disease_name, COUNT(DISTINCT id)
FROM disease_table
GROUP BY disease_name
```

where each disease_name has an associated identifier, and a disease may occur multiple times for the same identifier.

This works, BUT it takes roughly **7s to run**.

If I run this query:

```
SELECT disease_name, COUNT(disease_name)
FROM disease_table
GROUP BY disease_name
```

it takes **321ms**, BUT duplicate rows (same disease with same id) are counted more than once.

Is there a more efficient way to achieve the results of the first query in about the same time as the second using only SQL?

**Table:**

```
disease_name     |         id
------------     |    -------------  
dis_1                      123
dis_1                      104
dis_1                      104
dis_32                     123
dis_12                     123
dis_12                     115
```

**Expected:**

```
disease_name     |        count
------------     |    -------------  
dis_1                      2
dis_32                     1
dis_12                     2
```

where dis_1 has 3 entries but is only counted twice because two of those 3 entries have the same id

Comment: Can you show what you are getting as a result with no distinct? Also, why are changing the count from `id` to `disease_name`?

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Server or Postgre?

Comment: well, if you are counting distinct of the name, grouping by the name, it will always be 1, so what's the point?

Comment: There is overhead when using the DISTINCT clause, because the data structure that contains the results must be searched for duplicates (likely upon insertion). I could come up with a few other ways to write this query, but I'm not certain that it will increase your execution time without actually trying them against your database.

Comment: What indexes do you have on your table? Roughly how many rows are you dealing with?

Comment: which index you have on the related  table  ?

Comment: ^  Indexes may be your best bet for improving performance in this scenario, since there isn't really anything wrong with the first query. As I noted before, using DISTINCT has overhead because the results must be iterated through to remove duplicates. However, something else is wrong here. You said duplicate rows are being counted because they have the same ID and NAME. How do they have the same ID? It must not be a primary key. Do you have a PK on this table?

Comment: You should tag correctly your question. Or its postgresql or Mysql or it´s sql-server and it looks like there is no python there

Comment: tag the correct db please

Comment: @scaisEdge 840,500 entries in the table

Comment: postgreSQL server

Comment: counting id's WITHOUT distinct will count multiple rows with matching disease names and identifiers (I only want to count the number of unique rows ONCE)

Comment: update your question and show you table  schema and indexes ..

Answer (score 1):

Try to add a proper index on `disease_table`, like this:

```
CREATE INDEX ON disease_table(disease_name, id);
```

See if that solves out your issue.

Comment: why the double ()'s?  `CREATE INDEX ON disease_table(disease_name, id);`

Comment: Well after researching some, this seems like a good approach. I am not the owner of the table however, and have been denied access to create an index as a result. Thanks for your help.